# How to manually enter rows into Parse.com web interface?

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to manually add rows to the Roles or Users table from the Parse.com web interface/dashboard?

Most data types are easy to add but what about the relation and object id columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of this writing the data browser is terrible for the more advanced columns, so the answer to your question is no. Hopefully they're working on a more robust version. Keep an eye on http://blog.parse.com/ and cross your fingers.